# Get step index from Angular Material Design Stepper

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I am trying to get the selected step in an component that is using Angular Material Design stepper.

The thing is that I am trying to get it by using selectedIndex property, but now is always getting "1" when I try to get it

```html
        <button mat-button mat-flat-button color="primary"
                (click)="onSave(stepper)">
          SAVE
        </button>
```

```
onSave(stepper: MatStepper)
  {
    debugger;
    let workflowStepName = this.declarationWorkflowHelper.getWorkflowName(stepper.selectedIndex);

    this.screenSave.next(workflowStepName);
  }
```

I expect the selected index of the stepper, but I am always retrieving "1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set explicitly `stepControl` to your `matStep`. E.g. `firstFormGroup`, `secondFormGroup` :

```
<mat-step [stepControl]="firstFormGroup">
    <form [formGroup]="firstFormGroup">
      <!-- The code is omitted for the brevity -->
      <div>
        <button mat-button matStepperNext>Next</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </mat-step>
  <mat-step [stepControl]="secondFormGroup">
    <form [formGroup]="secondFormGroup">
      <!-- The code is omitted for the brevity --> 
     <div>
        <button mat-button matStepperPrevious>Back</button>
        <button mat-button matStepperNext>Next</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </mat-step>
```